# Enum case 'poweredon' is not a member of type 'CBManagerState'

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am getting error while using the "CBPeripheralManager" here is my code

extension BLEPeripheralManager:CBPeripheralManagerDelegate{

```
func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager){

    print("state updated\(peripheral.state)")

    switch(peripheral.state){

    case CBPeripheralManagerState.poweredOn:
        self.delegate?.blePeripheralManager(self, communicatorInitializationSuccessWithBluetoothState:BluetoothState.PoweredOn)
        break

    case CBPeripheralManagerState.poweredOff:
        self.delegate?.blePeripheralManager(self, communicatorInitializationFailWithBluetoothState: BluetoothState.PoweredOff)
        break

    case CBPeripheralManagerState.resetting:
        self.delegate?.blePeripheralManager(self, communicatorInitializationFailWithBluetoothState: BluetoothState.Resetting)
        break

    case CBPeripheralManagerState.unauthorized:
        self.delegate?.blePeripheralManager(self, communicatorInitializationFailWithBluetoothState: BluetoothState.Unauthorized)
        break

    case CBPeripheralManagerState.unknown:
        self.delegate?.blePeripheralManager(self, communicatorInitializationFailWithBluetoothState: BluetoothState.Unknown)
        break

    case CBPeripheralManagerState.unsupported:
        self.delegate?.blePeripheralManager(self, communicatorInitializationFailWithBluetoothState: BluetoothState.Unsupported)
        break

    }
}
```

[Screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0cwf.png)

Comment: Look carefully in your error message: `CBManagerState.enumValue`, and you wrote `CBPeripheralManagerState.enumValue`. There has been a little change.

Comment: Check screenshot of error

Comment: What I'm saying: `CBManagerState` != `CBPeripheralManagerState` (but the uses and values are the same). CoreBluetooth.framework has changed in iOS10 (I think). `peripheral.state` is a `CBManagerState` value, not a `CBPeripheralManagerState`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CBCentralManager iOS10 and iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450534/cbcentralmanager-ios10-and-ios9)

Comment: Thanks @Larme this helped